# Can anyone tell me what these hackers are attempting to do on my website?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, security

I have had the following attack recently, where POST requests have been sent to the webserver with the following code (url encoding has been removed to show the actual query, and 'example.com' has been substituted for the actual address)

```
/page.php?Story_ID=2494" onmousedown="ct(this, "http://example.com/page.php?Story_ID=2494','45','8','*.eg+page.php?','', '0095cae1ce41b064a7268177db4b654c44e914f95761d81211b8', 0)/contact.php
```

I have searched for language references for ct that would enable me to understand what this is doing - but it has been hard to find. Any ideas?

Comment: simple XSS ... since is using only Javascript, and search chat ``ct()`` function does, if you have it on your website

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Cross-site scripting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) attack.

They are trying to inject automatically opening links to their spam.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like they are trying to inject some javascript into your page